# ios 7 uitabbarcontroller subview bounds incorrect after rotation

Tags: rotation, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I've been trying to update my app for iOS 7. It has worked fine on ios 5 & 6. I have created an example of what is happening. I have a uitabbarcontroller as the root view and a standard uiviewcontroller as a child. in said child, I have 2 switches, one near the bottom-center and one right-aligned and vertically centered. The app supports all orientations. When I rotate from landscape to portrait or vice-versa, one of the switches no longer works. the bounds of the child view but the bounds of the superviews seem to correspond to the old orientation, causing the switch to be visible but outside of the parent view. why is this happening and even more importantly, how do i fix it?

Pics attached, grey background is the superview of the tab bar controllers child view.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made all the superviews resizing mask to be  `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`. Not sure why this wasn't a problem before ios 7 but this seems to fix it.